# Validate a svn up on Windows using powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

I have written a powershell code which updates a svn repository. I want to properly validate if the 'svn up' actually worked. I had initially checked for return code 0 to validate this but saw that when the working repository is locked and 'svn up' did not work, still it returned a 0 which is not correct. What is the correct way of checking if the update actually ran till the end ?

This is what I have right now.

```
$Run = start-process $exe $arguments -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru 
if ($Run.ExitCode -eq 0){
exit 0 }
else{
exit 1}
```

I am thinking of capturing the StandardOutput of the process and tailing the file to check if it contains 'At Revision' string. Can I get some other suggestions please ?

```
$Run = start-process $exe $arguments -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput $svnLogFile
$output=Get-Content $svnLogFile -Tail 1
if ($Run.ExitCode -eq 0 -and $output -like 'At Revision*' ){
exit 0}
else {
exit 1}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `Start-Process`? Just run the command and check the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

Comment: I can try that but the issue in question is svn is not returning a proper exit code for lock conditions. Should have returned 1 but returned 0.